# Php-debug on atom doesn't work

Tags: xdebug, atom-editor

Is anyone has done successfully on php debug integration on atom?

I tried to follow the steps from this [link](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug) and from [this](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

but this part

> If everything worked correctly, you can now use the various
>   buttons/commands to step through the script.

doesn't work,

I am using xampp, bundle with php7, the problem, it doesn't work.

Does anyone done this before, can explain why?

of the instruction from [php-debug](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491962), but kept getting a connection timeout after 200ms.

Re-installing Atom worked for me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but as I had the same problem it might be useful for someone.

In my case I needed to change the variable in the php.ini file

```
xdebug.remote_log=C:\xampp\htdocs\log\xdebug.log
```

This way you can see in the log if xdebug is working and if you are in error you can see the error

After analyzing the error, I changed the variables

```
xdebug.remote_host=10.20.200.100 #Use your IP
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

I added it too

```
xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom
```

It was as follows

```
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.20.200.100 #Use your IP
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=false
xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom
xdebug.remote_log=C:\xampp\htdocs\log\xdebug.log
```

In the php-debug configuration on the Atom

```
"php-debug":
   GutterBreakpointToggle: false
   PathMaps: [
     "\"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject;C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\""
   ]
   ServerAddress: "10.20.200.100" <--Use your IP
```

These steps worked for me.